Ring where all elements are zero divisors.
I know that the collection of all nilpotent elements in a commutative ring form such a ring where all elements are zero divisors. For example, if we take $S=\lbrace 0,2,4,6 \rbrace$ as a subring of $\mathbb{Z_8}$, then all elements of $S$ are zero divisors and nilpotent. If we look at $\mathbb{Z_{p^n}}$, then we arrive at another example of this. But I'm struggling to find a well-known example where not every element is nilpotent. More specifically, I want to find such a ring that at least one of the element of the ring is a zero divisor but not nilpotent. How should I think of such an example?

I gather that by "ring" you mean ring without 1.

No it may have a unity

Well $1$ can never be a zero divisor.

" I want to find such a ring that atleast one of the element of the ring is a zero divisor but not nilpotent." - split-complex numbers.

What about $\{0,3,6,9,12,15\}$ where addition and multiplication is $\pmod{18}$?

This should work.

or ${0,2,4,6,8,10}$ $\pmod{12}$?

More generally, $k\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\subset\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (where "$k$" divides "$n$") will always give an example of a finite ring in which every element is a zero divisor, as well -- in most cases -- where no elements are nilpotent.

@JAG131:  if $n=k^2$, all the elements of $k\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ are nilpotent; if $n=kl$, where $k $ and $l$ are distinct primes, then $k\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ does not have nonzero zero divisors

@J.W.Tanner You are correct with your first statement (notice that I specified that you'll have non-nilpotent elements in most cases :) ). And you make a good point with your second statement...I think I was in the headspace of the additive group (in which case, yes, every element would have an additive inverse...though that's to be expected coming from a ring). My bad. So I guess maybe a better way to phrase that initial comment is that $k\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ may provide a good example for a ring of interest under certain conditions.

@JAG131: such as $n=k^2l$ with $\gcd(k,l)=1$

I think this ring will work as well $R=\Bigg\lbrace
\begin{pmatrix} 0& a \\
0 & b  \\
\end{pmatrix}|a,b \in \mathbb{Z}
\Bigg\rbrace$.

The residues $0,6,10,15\bmod 30$ form a multiplicative ring in which every element is idempotent while the product of any two distinct elements is $0$.

This is an interesting ring.
